# Correctly setting the measurement noise matrix when using the Apache Kalman filter

Tags: java, kalman-filter

In KalmanFilter.java from Apache's Kalman filter code, I found this line that I cannot explain:

```
} else if (measNoise.getRowDimension() != this.measurementMatrix.getRowDimension() || measNoise.getColumnDimension() != 1) {
                throw new MatrixDimensionMismatchException(measNoise.getRowDimension(), measNoise.getColumnDimension(), this.measurementMatrix.getRowDimension(), 1);
            }
```

Apparently the measurement noise should be an `N x 1` matrix and measurementMatrix should be an `N x ?` size matrix
However, I also found:

```
RealMatrix s = this.measurementMatrix.multiply(this.errorCovariance).multiply(this.measurementMatrixT).add(this.measurementModel.getMeasurementNoise());
```

So the `this.measurementMatrix.multiply(this.errorCovariance).multiply(this.measurementMatrixT)` part will result in an `N x N` matrix, which cannot be added to the `N x 1` matrix. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was a bug in a previous version of Apache's Kalman filter library (`org.apache.commons:commons-math3`). Upgrading to the latest (3.6.1) fixed the issue.